# Adding coordinate data to matrix elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I calculated matrices which took a long calculation time and now I want to interpolate them to a function f(x,y) but I just found out that i forgot to add the coordinate data to the table which I need to add in advance now without re-calculating the actual matrices.

Here is a simplified problem which I try to tackle:

What I want:

```
mat = Table[{x, y, x^2 + y^2}, {x, 0, 10, 1}, {y, 0, 10, 1}];
```

What I have:

```
mat2 = Table[x^2 + y^2, {x, 0, 10, 1}, {y, 0, 10, 1}];
```

I created the coordinate vectors

```
xtab = Table[x, {x, 0, 10, 1}];
ytab = Table[y, {y, 0, 10, 1}];
```

but how can I smartly combine them component wise to receive the wanted matrix? I already got desperate trying.

Comment: Why not just generate `tab = Table[{x, y}, {x, 0, 10, 1}, {y, 0, 10, 1}];`, and then join them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possibilities to do this (and probably a lot more that I can't think of but someone else will). It depends a bit on what kind of assumptions you can make about your data and what you can change about the snippets you have up there.

For example, if you can change `xtab` and `ytab`, it would be easier to generate them as full matrices immediately, and then use a simple transposition:

```
xtab = Table[x, {x, 0, 10, 1}, {y, 0, 10, 1}];
ytab = Table[y, {x, 0, 10, 1}, {y, 0, 10, 1}];

Transpose[{xtab, ytab, mat2}, {3, 1, 2}]
```

Alternatively, if you know that `x` and `y` are simply zero-based indices, you don't need to generate `xtab` and `ytab` at all. Instead, simply use `MapIndexed` and compute them based on the current index:

```
MapIndexed[{#2[[1]] - 1, #2[[2]] - 1, #} &, mat2, {2}]
```

Or slightly terser:

```
MapIndexed[Append[#2 - 1, #] &, mat2, {2}]
```

Finally, if you've really only got `mat2`, `xtab` and `ytab` to work with, I'd probably also go for `MapIndexed`:

```
MapIndexed[{xtab[[#2[[1]]]], ytab[[#2[[2]]]], #} &, mat2, {2}]
```

here, I'm using the components of the current index of `mat2` to index into `xtab` and `ytab`, respectively, which ensures I'm getting the right coordinate value for each of them.

Comment: The simple table joining you mentioned first in your answer already worked that out but I am also just playing around with MapIndexed to understand that. Thanks for the quick help!